# Monitor update and deletion in database using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

Am using grids in VB.net to display database records stored in Microsoft Access, the tables allow editing and deleting using the grid fields. 
Is there a way I can monitor whenever a user deletes or edits a record? I want to be able to view details of every update or deletion to certain records, such as the date and users who did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're speaking of is known as "auditing" and certain databases - such as MS SQL Server - have built-in support for this.  MS Access does not include this feature.  With the abscence of auditing, a common way to implement this in a custom manner is using update triggers.  Unfortunately MS Access also does not have triggers.  The only way you'll be able to do this is via an API you write yourself to interact with your tables and discipline to stick to that API.

Comment: Ya that seems to do it, I was able to find some code already created for it. Thank you.

Comment: Access 2010 has something very much akin to triggers, and that is Data Macros - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973807.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is hook into the save commands on your inserts and deletes.  You could also hook into the events to capture the data.  Either way, create an insert statement that dumps the log data into your log database.

Comment: I'm still only a beginner, do you know anywhere I can find how to do that, by any chance? Or what I should be looking at to learn more about it?